# package fontspec errors: the font "FandolSong-Regular"cannot be found when trying to use a latex template

Tags: xetex, ctex

I am trying to use Latex to write my resume. In order to do that, I downloaded a template from [here](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/freeman-cv).

Since I would like to write a Chinese resume, usually what I do is I add

```
\usepackage{ctex}
```

before the main document and specify Xelatex engine to compile the file.

This usually works, but not this time. After compiling the file, I encounter the error in the title.

I am not sure exactly what is going on here. My knowledge is pretty limited.I look up the .cls latex file, and it seems to me the author of the original template used his own font that cannot be used to render Chinese chracter. (Again, I'm just making wild guess here) I would like to know if there is a work-around here?

edit: macOS, texlive 2020

Comment: what is your OS? And which texsystem do you use?

Comment: I don't have your OS and I won't debug an external template, but you could try to force another fontset, e.g. `\usepackage[fontset=mac]{ctex}`.

Comment: The template page says about fonts: "This template uses the following fonts: EB Garamond, Freebooter Script, Libertinus Sans and FontAwesome. All four are supplied with the template so you don’t have to worry about installing them on your system. The licenses are supplied with the template and each has been generously licensed for redistribution." -- are you trying to adapt/remix/transform the template? Fonts must be accessible/installed (do you have the font?) and Xelatex is not as forgiving when trying to work out the font (e.g., `FangSong Regular` is not found, but `simfang.ttf` is found)

Comment: I definitely has everything installed. I am thinking maybe that font is only used for English character, so when I try to use the Chinese character, the system broke down? Is that a possible explanation? I actually don't know how fonts are rendered.

Comment: I think it's a MAC system problem, you need to specify the font file name.